# Question involving weak law of large numbers

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I am currently doing the following question from my textbook:

> Let $W_1$, $W2$,.. be i.i.d. with distribution Exponential(3). Prove that for some $n$,
> we have $P(W_1 + W_2 +···+ W_n < n/2) > 0.999$

This appears to be a fairly basic application of the weak law of large numbers. I used $P(W_1 +\cdots+ W_n < n/2) = 1 − P(W_1 +\cdots+ W_n ≥ n/2)$. At this point I assume that I need to apply the weak law of large numbers but I'm unsure on how to go about that. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You should state the density of $X$ in your question. There are two conventions for parameterization of the exponential distribution. One leads to $E X = 1/3$ and the other $E X = 3$.

Comment: Suppose $W \sim \mathrm{Exp}(3)$, that is, $\mathbb E W = 1/3$. Then by the weak law of large numbers, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $$\lim_n P(\lvert n^{-1}(W_1+\dots+W_n)-1/3\rvert \leq \varepsilon) = 1$$ Can you take it from there?